# using usort ignore

Tags: php, usort

Im trying to organize this kind of array

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => '19'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '0'
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => '23'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '2'
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => '45'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '0'
  3 => 
    array
      'id' => '6'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '0'
  4 => 
    array
      'id' => '23'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '1'
  5 => 
    array
      'id' => '12'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '0'
```

So, I have to put the zeros values in order to the end of the array, and using others order values to ordering correctely the array.

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => '23'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '1'
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => '23'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '2'
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => '19'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '0'
  3 => 
    array
      'id' => '45'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '0'
  4 => 
    array
      'id' => '6'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '0'
  5 => 
    array
      'id' => '12'
      'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum'
      'order' => '0'
```

I tried using usort like this, with not the correct result:

```
    usort($items, function() {
        if ($a['uf_order'] == 0) return 0;
        return ($a['uf_order'] > $b['uf_order']) ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass `$a` and `$b` in the function:

```
usort($items, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['uf_order'] == 0) return 0;
    return ($a['uf_order'] > $b['uf_order']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Also there is no key called `uf_order` in your array.

As [NomikOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117697/using-usort-ignore/12117721#comment16201775_12117721) correctly stated in his comment. This would only work in PHP 5.3+. If you have an older version of PHP you could do:

```
usort($items, 'cmp');

function cmp ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['uf_order'] == 0) return 0;
    return ($a['uf_order'] > $b['uf_order']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 OBS: this (using anonymous functions) only will works in php5.3+

Comment: thank you guys... I fix my code, but now I need to put an specific rule into order... I need to put it in the asc order, but inserting the zero order at the end, so first the items with order value equal 1, after 2, and at the end zero.